# how to connect a serverless client with a given AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a question about how to connect a serverless client with a given AWS Lambda function.

I'm building a system that provides the developers with a cloud-based dev environment.
It provides the serverless dev environment built atop the AWS lambda, dynamodb services.

Some developers ask me about how to use the serverless framework in the given environment.
For the company's security policy, I can't grant Adimin authority on the developers, so that they find it difficult to perform the sls deploy cmd that requires CRUD authority in the IAM service.

I've tried connecting the serverless client with the aws lambda provided by my system without executing the deploy cmd. But all failed.
It requires me to execute the sls deploy cmd before the deploy function cmd.

Is there any way to connect a serverless client with a given AWS Lambda function?
If there is a best practice in grating the minimized authority, please give me a suggestion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to setup different group with dedicated security groups granting rights to your users. Here's a Cloudformation template for instance, (it references default `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` but you might/should create your own with minimal access) :

```yaml
Resources:
  # ADMIN QA
  AssumeAdministratorQARolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: "AdminQA"
      Description: "Assume the qa administrative role"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Sid: "AssumeAdministratorQARolePolicy"
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
          - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Resource: "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"

  AdminQAGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
    Properties: 
      GroupName: AdminQA
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - !Ref AssumeAdministratorQARolePolicy

  AdminQAUsersToGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition
    Properties: 
      GroupName: !Ref AdminQAGroup
      Users: 
        - MYUSER
```

Then `MYUSER` might use this Role through his `.aws/credentials` like

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KEY
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET

[qa]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
source_profile = default
```

Once again you might update `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` to your very own Role.
Finally during deployment you might use this profile with :

```
serverless deploy --stage qa --aws-profile qa
```

Which I recommend to set in `package.json` directly.

Hope this helps and clarifies how you should grant rights and access through the whole deployment process.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try what you've told